# Getting paths to all files in a directory (but not absolute path) in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, operating-system

I have a directory **DATA** which contains several subdirectories and inside each subdirectory, there are more directories and files.

Here is my code:

```
for dirpath,subs,filenames in os.walk("/Users/.../DATA"):
   for f in filenames:
       print(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, f)))
```

The results this code prints out are the absolute directories (ex. "/Users/.../Data/SubFile/SubFile.txt")

The results I want are (ex. "Data/SubFile/Subfile.txt")

Answer (score 1):

What about something simple like this:

```
dir_path = "/Users/.../DATA"

for dirpath,subs,filenames in os.walk("/Users/.../DATA"):
   for f in filenames:
       print(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, f))[len(dir_path):])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [os.path.commonprefix()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.commonprefix):

```py
common_prefix = os.path.commonprefix(["/Users/.../DATA"])
for dirpath, subs, filenames in os.walk("/Users/.../DATA"):
    for f in filenames:
        print(os.path.relpath(os.path.join(dirpath, f), common_prefix))
```